# How can I rotate a Box2D body without applying a force to it?

Tags: c++, physics, box2d

Anyone know?  All I can see is ApplyTorque and SetAngularVelocity, I want to just rotate the object before adding it to the simulation, for example: so I have one crate tilted up against a wall and another flat.

Comment: Retagging this because it’s really specific to the API, and while it has many bindings, [language-agnostic] gives the wrong impression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `SetTransform`, you can specify the position and orientation of your object.

Comment: Thanks -- it's not SetTransform for me, maybe a different version of Box2D, but SetTransform showed intellisense for SetXForm and that works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like a [matrix rotation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix) will help you